# Should Django Python apps be stored in the web server document root?

Tags: python, django

As the title states, I'm trying to figure out the best practice for where to store application files for a Python website on the server. Document root, or no?

I come from a land of PHP. :)

EDIT - To that end, links to any material describing the best practice differences between Python and PHP are hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. WSGI containers don't require the scripts to be in the document root, and so to increase security in case of a transient server error they *shouldn't* be placed in the document root.

Comment: Where in the filesystem do you keep yours, by chance?

Comment: Either where the package installs it, or in a sibling directory of the document root.

Comment: But, if it's in a sibling directory of the document root, couldn't you theoretically-in-case-of-transient-error access it via browsing to that sibling directory? Doesn't seem like the logically secure next step.

Comment: A proper web server doesn't allow traversal into parent directories, making accessing a sibling directory impossible.

Comment: In a standard Linux filesystem `/srv` is a good place for it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to store it in the document root.

While storing the app in the doc root isn't nessescarily a security problem - if configured correctly and handled carefully - storing it outside will remove a lot of headache and configuration work.
That's the main reason *not* to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use https://bitbucket.org/acoobe/django-starter/ layout with buildout. So developed apps goes to apps folder and just used apps goes to parts/eggs folders (parts for packets from git, mercurial or svn and eggs for pypi located apps).

So the answer is NO. Everything should be placed in separate tidied folders. All your server need to know were is wsgi script and where is var dir. Well just like everyone else here said.

Answer (score 0):

Everything has been said I think, so I will only elaborate a bit. Here is an explanation of how Apache maps URLs to files on disk: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html. As you can see, the base rule is that only the files within DocumentRoot are exposed to the outside world. You can change that by doing the explicit import of other files or folders using e.g. [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) directive.

Now, you obviously don't want your Python scripts to be exposed to everyone - which means that you should keep them outside DocumentRoot and any other folder "imported" to  DocumentRoot (using e.g. the mentioned *Alias* directive). What you want to do instead is to merely hook given URL to your Python program - if you use mod_wsgi, this can be done with [WSGIScriptAlias](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIScriptAlias) directive. In other words, you should map the effects (result) of your script to given URL, instead of mapping the files themselves.

So - where you should keep your Python files? I would say it's a matter of personal taste - some people advise to not keep them in user folder (i.e. */home/xyz/*) because e.g. Apache configuration flaw may expose user folders to the outside world. What's left? E.g. /usr/local/, /var/www - there's really no magic in picking home folder for your scripts.

Comment: It is good practice though to NOT put the WSGI script file in the same directory as your Django settings file. This is because you have to tell Apache that the directory the WSGI file is in can be served, even though no Alias directive exists to it, from that directory. It is better to put the WSGI script file in an otherwise empty subdirectory of where the Django settings file is, if you want to keep it with the project. Then only that subdirectory would be allowed access by Apache.

Comment: @Graham: How could the directory with WSGI script be reached (i.e. what URL points to it) ?

Comment: It is a case of you having removed one of Apache's level of protection. If someone mucked up the configuration in some way or added a symlink in a directory which was exposed via a URL that could get to the directory and follow symlinks was enabled as it often is, then settings.py could be got too. So, it just being super conservative, rather than that one level of additional protection that using 'Allow from all' on the directory removes, you avoid the risk altogether. If you don't feel the need to be paranoid about security then not an issue.

Comment: @Graham: Ok, thanks for the explanation - I *am* paranoid about security :)